# jQuery-File-Upload-9.7.0 doesn't works on my jsp webpage

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use Jboss server application and i want to use jQuery-File-Upload-9.7.0, so when i start the upload image, it display Error, I don't understand why?

https://imageshack.us/download/907/Jnxlas.png

main.js:

```
 $(function () {
'use strict';

// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: '//localhost:8080/CA/tmpch/'
});

// Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
$('#fileupload').fileupload(
    'option',
    'redirect',
    window.location.href.replace(
        /\/[^\/]*$/,
        '/cors/result.html?%s'
    )
);

if (window.location.hostname === 'localhost:8080') {
    // Demo settings:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
        url: '//localhost:8080/CA/tmpch/',
        // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
        // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
        // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
        maxFileSize: 5000000,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
    });
    // Upload server status check for browsers with CORS support:
    if ($.support.cors) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '//localhost:8080/CA/tmpch/',
            type: 'HEAD'
        }).fail(function () {
            $('<div class="alert alert-danger"/>')
                .text('Upload server currently unavailable - ' +
                        new Date())
                .appendTo('#fileupload');
        });
    }
} else {
    // Load existing files:
    $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
    $.ajax({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
        dataType: 'json',
        context: $('#fileupload')[0]
    }).always(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
    }).done(function (result) {
        $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
            .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
    });
}
```

});

partial code of my page MyPage.jsp:

```
<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Templates plugin is included to render the upload/download listings -->
<script
src="http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Templates/js/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
<script
src="http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
<script
src="http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS is not required, but included for the responsive demo navigation -->
<script
src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- blueimp Gallery script -->
<script
src="http://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload processing plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload image preview & resize plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload user interface plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
<!-- The File Upload validation plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
<!-- The main application script -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>


    <!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
        <form id="fileupload" action="UploadServlet" method="POST"
            enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
            <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button"> <i
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> <span>Add files...</span> <input
                        type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                    </span>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i> <span>Start
                            upload</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i> <span>Cancel
                            upload</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
                    <!-- The global file processing state -->
                    <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- The global progress state -->
                <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
                    <!-- The global progress bar -->
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar"
                        aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 0%;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                    <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
            <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped">
                <tbody class="files"></tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
        <br>





 <!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
<tr class="template-upload fade">
<td>
<span class="preview"></span>
</td>
<td>
<p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
<strong class="error text-danger"></strong>
</td>
<td>
 <p class="size">Processing...</p>
 <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
 </td>
 <td>
 {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
 <button class="btn btn-primary start" disabled>
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
 <span>Start</span>
 </button>
 {% } %}
 {% if (!i) { %}
 <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
 <span>Cancel</span>
 </button>
 {% } %}
 </td>
 </tr>
 {% } %}
 </script>
 <!-- The template to display files available for download -->
 <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
 {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
 <tr class="template-download fade">
 <td>
 <span class="preview">
 {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
 <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}"  data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
 {% } %}
 </span>
 </td>
 <td>
 <p class="name">
 {% if (file.url) { %}
 <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}"    {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
{% } else { %}
<span>{%=file.name%}</span>
{% } %}
</p>
{% if (file.error) { %}
<div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
{% } %}
</td>
<td>
<span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
</td>
<td>
{% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
<button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="  {%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
<span>Delete</span>
</button>
<input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
{% } else { %}
<button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
<span>Cancel</span>
</button>
 {% } %}
 </td>
 </tr>
 {% } %}
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: hi i think your getting a bit confussed at the point this page loads its already processing the bottom part of the jsp page before your javascript kicks in so it wont show you a progress. to do this you would want some on page ajax. thats how i tackled it. i assume you are building a multi file uploader?. if so break down the process client and server side try getting a single file to upload via ajax and see if the server side works. i.e can you see it on the server. if you can't then you need to work out why its not.

Comment: You might also need to tell your servlet or jsp page your posting a file. this is doing using javascript on the ajax reequest by setting form type. I think if your trying to reload the page each time that generates alot of page refreshes when all you need to do is upload a file return true or false. if true move onto next file if false error.

Comment: You don't also have to upload a file to get a preview you can load this on the fly with javascript if the result from uploading was true

Comment: I have the preview image but when i click on Upload button, the progress bar display and i get Error message.

Comment: now, i'm always blocked with this problem, Any ideas?